# W3TotalCache and Javascript -- what should go where, when?

Tags: css, javascript, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I'm just starting to use W3TotalCache and am a little perplexed by how I should load the gobs of javascript and CSS rendering on the site in the question. Adding some of the pre-minified jQuery scripts via the Minified wizard in W3TotalCache breaks them when loading on the site; same with CSS.

When you have a boatload of modules, what are some good rules of thumb when moving around javascript/css for minification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the best method is to do a view source then add the scripts to W3 in the same order they are listed in the source using the same url including the query string.

Most problems are from plugins or themes that output javascript inline.  I try to move these to a custom.js file that is always listed last on W3.

If any scripts break when when minified either leave them out of minify or use combine only.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any rules or guides to go by and every time i used **W3TotalCache** i simply run "Trail & Error".

The only guide line i have is to include as many scripts and styles as possible without breaking them via he Minified wizard, This saves the browser a few GET calls for each page.